# QBO3 Saving Related Records

Tags: forms, foreign-keys, relationship, qbo3

I have a custom QBO3 page that renders data from multiple tables custom tables:

- `Foo`: parent table
- `Bar`: related table 1

  - `Foo.BarID` is a foreign key constraint to the `Bar` table
- `Crunch`: child table 2

My `Foo/Summary` page renders all of my Foo columns, as well as:

- Bar record: `Bar.FieldA`, `Bar.FieldB`
- First Crunch record: `Crunch.FieldC`, `Crunch.FieldD`
- Second Crunch record: `Crunch.FieldC`, `Crunch.FieldD`

Can I I map these HTML form input values to the `Bar` and `Crunch` tables via `Foo/Save`, or do I need to call `Foo/Save`, `Bar/Save`, and `Crunch/Save` (twice)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; post the following parameters to Foo/Save:

```
Foo.ashx/Save?ID=X
  &Bar_FieldA=BA
  &Bar_FieldB=BB
  &Crunches_0_FieldC=CC1
  &Crunches_0_FieldD=CD1
  &Crunches_1_FieldC=CC2
  &Crunches_1_FieldD=CD2
```

QBO's `AbstractObject/Save` method supports persisting data to any related tables that QBO3 is aware of. This includes:

- Foreign keys (for C# properties tagged with a `ForeignKey` attribute)
- Children (for C# properties tagged with `Child` attribute)
- Child classes (configured in the `ObjectConfiguration` for the class)

When `Foo/Save` is called, `AbstractObject/SetProperties` will:

**Check for foreign key parameters**

`AbstractObject` will loop through every defined foreign key (including `Foo.BarID`), and if parameters beginning with `{ForeignKey}` (minus an ID) exist, set properties for the foreign key object. If `Foo.BarID` is defined along these lines in Foo.Fields.cs, this will work:

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(my.Namespace.BarObject), "Bar")]
public Int64 BarID {...}
```

**Check for collections of child class properties**

`AbstractObject` will loop through every configured child class, and if parameters beginning with `ChildClass.Name` exist, create a collection of child objects and set properties on the collection. For this to work, you must:

Include `Crunches` as a child class for `Foo` in `Foo.config`:

```
<ChildClasses>
  <Child Name="Crunches" Type="my.Namespace.CrunchObject, my.Namespace"/>
</ChildClasses>
```

Since child classes imply a 1:many relationship, the collection (implemented by `AbstractCollection<T>`) expects each Crunch record to share a common 0-based prefix.

**Note**: that an alternative to the configuration-driven child class is to create a C# property called `Crunches` using this pattern:

```
[Child(typeof(CrunchObject)), XmlIgnore] 
public CrunchCollection Crunches {...}
```

where `CrunchCollection` derives from `AbstractCollection<CrunchObject>`, adding known types:

```
[KnownType(typeof(CrunchCollection))]
[KnownType(typeof(CrunchObject))]
public class CrunchCollection : AbstractCollection<CrunchObject>
{...}
```

This allows `AbstractObject` to instantiate collections via reflection with knowing the data types at compile time.